# Expression Language for Compositing Purposes?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am really unfamiliar with Compositing in Blender and couldn't find any questions about this in my research.  Does Blender support expression language for compositing purposes?

Ie) G=R>G?(R+G)/2:G

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry Tyler,

this is currently not possible. Someone might be able to create an add-on that converts the expression to a node setup. But I don't think this has been done yet. It was on my mind to implement this, but haven't got time to do this yet.

Comment: Oh gotcha.  Hey that’s good to know though.  Thanks for the response:)